# ionic 3 angular different UI on android and ios

Tags: android, css, angular, ionic3

i am using ionic 3 angular and using ion-scroll to lay a horizontal scrollable area which renders some buttons. the code looks like

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true" style="width:100vw;height:49px">
            <ion-row nowrap >
            <button *ngFor="let item of messageQueue.shortcutList" ion-button small round (click)="processShortcut(item.action)">{{item.action}}</button>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-scroll>
```

this looks perfect on ios but on android the rendered button size is is fixed and so text is cut.

please see the screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/0amwir62acliccn/Screenshot%202017-08-08%2015.32.21.png?dl=0

Comment: image does not seem to work, you can upload it to imgur

Comment: try now plz it should work

Comment: I'm not using Ionic but, overflow seems to be disabled on android, maybe if you enable it with css `overflow: auto` it will then work on both ios and android ui.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you want this but if you don't want the app to have the native look of each device you can make the application default to something.

```
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
        mode: 'md'
    })
],
```

In this case it defaults to the material look.

Comment: This was the solution i searched. Also +1 to @Vik for asking the related question.